# Using simplenews in conjunction with sendgrid is possible?

Tags: 8, emails

I have installed and configured the [simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) and [sengrid module](https://www.drupal.org/project/sendgrid_integration). Sendgrid depends on [mailsystem](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem). When the module is installed, it configures itself.

I've done the test posts that sendgrid provides in the module and it works fine.

Now I am trying to send the simplenews nodes but I can't get them to send.

Is this integration possible or something additional needs to be developed to make it work.

I have configured it as follows

[image]

Comment: The simplenews module only creates the news and sends it out. As far as I know, it does not tie into its own SMTP services or anything. I'm thinking you're misdiagonising your problem.

Comment: In the tests I carried out with simplenews, by itself it does not send the newsletters, with the smtp module I have managed to send them. Right now in pantheon I have not been able to send through smtp, so I am trying another alternative.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Are you getting any errors over at `/admin/reports/dblog`? can you post your mail system configuration settings? Did you check the Spam folder in your inbox?